# Overlap and maintain fluid layout when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to overlap an image and a svg(inline). Also I'm trying to maintain the fluid layout.

This is my code. The images overlap correctly. But when resizing the browser, the 2 files does not scale down eqaliy.

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<img src="img/png.png" style="position: relevent; z-index: 1; display:block; margin: 0 auto; max-width:400px; width:100%;" />
<svg class="containerA" preserveAspectRatio= "xMinYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 200 240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
////some stuff
</svg></div>
```

css

```
.containerA{
    margin-top:10px;
    display: block;
    position: relevent;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainContainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:400px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a live example on jsfiddle or something for us to debug. What you're trying to do is not trivial in most cases

Comment: You'll almost certainly find this easier if you use an SVG <image> element in the SVG rather than an HTML <img> element outside it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
.containerA {
    margin-top:10px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.pngIMG{
    max-width:400px;
} /*For the PNG image, define a class to it. Avoid inline CSS.*/
body {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainContainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:400px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Also use [media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .containerA, .pngIMG {
        max-width:100%;
        width: 100%;
    } /*For the PNG image, define a class to it. Avoid inline CSS.*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the flux layout (FWD).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_web_design

It will scale and maintain the layout, its a bit complex but allows for a page to resize without pushing the content like (RWD).

It looks like responsive but it is scaling.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRcBMLI4jbg

You can find the CSS scaling formula here:

http://plugnedit.com/pnew/928-2/